# How do I send a list as a text file (ASP.NET Core web API)?

Tags: c#, file, asp.net-core, text, webapi

I am building an ASP.NET Core web API project.

I get the data from the database in the controller:

```
public IActionResult GetPosts()
{
     var data = _context.posts.firstOrDefault(//expression...)
            
     // Converting data to string...

     return // data as a text file...
}
```

Now I have to convert the ***data*** into a string and send it as a text file.

How can I do this?

Thank you for helping me

Comment: So what is data and how should the string look like?

Comment: In your question title you mention you want to send a list of elements as a text file. But in your code you use `.FirstOrDefault()`. Whatever is in your `var data` will not be a list of elements but a single one.

Comment: Why do you want text data?do you convert list to text?why do you use Json?

Answer (score 0):

In this case its pretty simple, check if ***data*** is null and then grab all the details you need and add to a list of strings and then write all the elements in the list to the text file after a concatenating the elements of the list with a hyphen

```
var data = _contexts.posts.FirstOrDefault();
//initialize an empty list 
var list = new List<string>();
//check if it's null
if(data != null){
  //get the post object attributes returned from the database
  var id = data.Id.ToString();;
  var title = data.Title;
  var body = data.Body;
  var postedOn = data.PostedOn.ToString();
  //add the data the list
  list.Add(id);
  list.Add(title);
  list.Add(body);
  list.Add(postedOn);
  
  //join the strings based on the hyphen 
  var sent = string.Join("-",list);
  //write the data to a text file
  using(var writer = new StreamWriter("data.txt", false)){
    writer.Write(sent);
  }
  
}
```

Comment: Or use XML common used formats like XML or JSON (both have APIs or builtin functions that do that for you), or a custom formatting like your answer. The problem is that because the question lacks key information (mainly desired output), your answer can be useful, or not useful at all.

Comment: @Cleptus, yeap that depends on whether or not my answer worked. Only OP can test and give feedback.

Answer (score 0):

We consider a Generic list assuming that it is a string:

```
TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter("SavedList.txt");

foreach (String s in Lists.verbList)
   tw.WriteLine(s);

tw.Close();
```

another method

```
using(TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter("SavedList.txt"))
{
   foreach (String s in Lists.verbList)
      tw.WriteLine(s);
}
```